# Slider Control (Trackbar) receiving messages in dialog box procedure

Tags: c++, winapi, win32gui

I'm designing a dialog box in Visual Studio resource editor, and the problem is that I don't know how to listen for messages sent by slider control, below the image is a dialog procedure.

I know I need to listen for `WM_NOTIFY` message but I don't know what code does a control send me... I added 2 comments in `WM_NOTIFY` part of the procedure below to show where is the problem...

here is an image how I arranged this dialog box:
[image]

And here is dialog box procedure:

```
INT_PTR CALLBACK SettingsSoundProc(HWND hDlg, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    static MainWindow* main_win = nullptr;

    switch (uMsg)
    {
    case WM_INITDIALOG:
    {
        main_win = reinterpret_cast<MainWindow*>(lParam);

        SetWindowText(GetDlgItem(hDlg, IDC_VOLUME_LABEL), TEXT("Music"));
        SendMessage(GetDlgItem(hDlg, IDC_VOLUME_SLIDER), TBM_SETRANGE, (WPARAM)FALSE, MAKELPARAM(0, 100));
        SendMessage(GetDlgItem(hDlg, IDC_VOLUME_SLIDER), TBM_SETPOS, (WPARAM)TRUE, (LPARAM)20);

        return TRUE;
    }
    case WM_COMMAND:
        switch (LOWORD(wParam))
        {
        case IDOK:

            EndDialog(hDlg, 0);
            return TRUE;

        case IDCANCEL:
            EndDialog(hDlg, 0);
            return TRUE;

        default:
            break;
        }

    case WM_NOTIFY:
    {
        LPNMHDR nmhdr = (LPNMHDR)lParam;

        if (nmhdr->idFrom == IDC_VOLUME_SLIDER)
        {
            switch (nmhdr->code)
            {
            // what message do I listen for here?
            case TB_THUMBTRACK:
            case WM_HSCROLL:
            case WM_VSCROLL:
            case TRBN_THUMBPOSCHANGING:
            case TB_PAGEUP:
            case TB_PAGEDOWN:
            case TB_THUMBPOSITION:
            case TB_TOP:
            case TB_BOTTOM:
            case TB_ENDTRACK:

                // this is never hit
                MessageBox(nullptr, TEXT("Message"), TEXT("Info"), MB_OK);
                break;

            default:
                // this is hit!
                abort();
            }
        }

        return TRUE;
    }
    case WM_DESTROY:
        EndDialog(hDlg, 0);
        return TRUE;

    default:
        break;
    }

    return FALSE;
}
```

As you can see `WM_HSCROLL` nor `TRBN_THUMBPOSCHANGING` is being hit, what message do I need to listen for here?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/controls/trackbar-controls#trackbar-notification-messages

Comment: I did read documentation several times and these are not the codes of the message ex. when checking `nmhdr.code` as my example above shows. `TB_THUMBTRACK` is not hit!

Comment: Read the documentation more closely. The parent control is sent WM_HSCROLL.

Comment: I see and that indeed works, but why does WM_NOTIFY do then why is being sent? never mind...

Comment: Log the arguments when you receive WM_NOTIFY

Comment: Forgot to say. Thank you for helping!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`WM_HSCROLL`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/Controls/wm-hscroll) and [`WM_VSCROLL`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/Controls/wm-vscroll) are their own messages, they are not wrapped in `WM_NOTIFY`.

The `TB_...` values are not `WM_NOTIFY` notification codes, either. They are reason codes reported in the [`NMTRBTHUMBPOSCHANGING`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/Commctrl/ns-commctrl-tagtrbthumbposchanging) struct of the [`TRBN_THUMBPOSCHANGING`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/Controls/trbn-thumbposchanging) notification.

Per [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/controls/trackbar-control-reference), the only `WM_NOTIFY` notifications that a Trackbar sends are:

- [`NM_CUSTOMDRAW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/Controls/nm-customdraw-trackbar)
- [`NM_RELEASEDCAPTURE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/Controls/nm-releasedcapture-trackbar-)
- [`TRBN_THUMBPOSCHANGING`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/Controls/trbn-thumbposchanging)

Try this:

```cpp
INT_PTR CALLBACK SettingsSoundProc(HWND hDlg, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    static MainWindow* main_win = nullptr;
    static HWND hSlider = nullptr;

    switch (uMsg)
    {
        case WM_INITDIALOG:
        {
            main_win = reinterpret_cast<MainWindow*>(lParam);
            hSlider = GetDlgItem(hDlg, IDC_VOLUME_SLIDER);
            SetWindowText(GetDlgItem(hDlg, IDC_VOLUME_LABEL), TEXT("Music"));
            SendMessage(hSlider, TBM_SETRANGE, FALSE, MAKELPARAM(0, 100));
            SendMessage(hSlider, TBM_SETPOS, TRUE, 20);
            return TRUE;
        }

        case WM_DESTROY:
        {
            EndDialog(hDlg, 0);
            return TRUE;
        }

        case WM_COMMAND:
        {
            switch (LOWORD(wParam))
            {
                case IDOK:
                    EndDialog(hDlg, 0);
                    return TRUE;

                case IDCANCEL:
                    EndDialog(hDlg, 0);
                    return TRUE;
            }
            break;
        }

        case WM_NOTIFY:
        {
            LPNMHDR nmhdr = reinterpret_cast<LPNMHDR>(lParam);
            if ((nmhdr->code == TRBN_THUMBPOSCHANGING) &&
                (nmhdr->hwndFrom == hSlider))
            {
                NMTRBTHUMBPOSCHANGING *nmtrb = reinterpret_cast<NMTRBTHUMBPOSCHANGING*>(lParam);
                switch (nmtrb->nReason)
                {
                    case TB_THUMBTRACK:
                    case TB_PAGEUP:
                    case TB_PAGEDOWN:
                    case TB_THUMBPOSITION:
                    case TB_TOP:
                    case TB_BOTTOM:
                    case TB_ENDTRACK:
                        MessageBox(nullptr, TEXT("Thumb Pos Changing"), TEXT("Info"), MB_OK);
                        break;
                }
            }
            break;
        }

        case WM_HSCROLL:
        {
            if ((lParam != 0) &&
                (reinterpret_cast<HWND>(lParam) == hSlider))
            {
                switch (LOWORD(wParam))
                {
                    case SB_ENDSCROLL:
                    case SB_LEFT:
                    case SB_RIGHT:
                    case SB_LINELEFT:
                    case SB_LINERIGHT:
                    case SB_PAGELEFT:
                    case SB_PAGERIGHT:
                    case SB_THUMBPOSITION:
                    case SB_THUMBTRACK:
                        MessageBox(nullptr, TEXT("Horz Scroll"), TEXT("Info"), MB_OK);
                        break;
                }
            }
            break;
        }

        case WM_VSCROLL:
        {
            if ((lParam != 0) &&
                (reinterpret_cast<HWND>(lParam) == hSlider))
            {
                switch (LOWORD(wParam))
                {
                    case SB_BOTTOM:
                    case SB_ENDSCROLL:
                    case SB_LINEDOWN:
                    case SB_LINEUP:
                    case SB_PAGEDOWN:
                    case SB_PAGEUP:
                    case SB_THUMBPOSITION:
                    case SB_THUMBTRACK:
                    case SB_TOP:
                        MessageBox(nullptr, TEXT("Vert Scroll"), TEXT("Info"), MB_OK);
                        break;
                }
            }
            break;
        }
    }

    return FALSE;
}
```